# Mac replacement for fiddler's auto-responder feature

Tags: macos, http, mocking, fiddler, charles-proxy

Fiddler lets me intercept http requests and respond with files from from my local machine. I am looking for a tool that does exactly that, on mac.

I tested charles but its "rewrite tool" does not allow that. I tried also httpscoop which allows only looking at requests, and wireshark where I could not even find the gui (probably due to my noobness on mac)

Comment: So far I found a nice FF extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-response/?src=search but it is not compatible with ff17, and of course it is specific to ff, its not a proxy. 
Robohydra could also be helpful, but it is not exactly what I am looking for (http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/using-robohydra-as-a-mock-server/). I still miss fiddler's simplicity.

Comment: As far as I understand it, Charles' "map" feature does this. If you have a Windows PC or VM on your Mac, you can use Fiddler there. (Also worth noting is that I'm at Telerik now and one of our goals is to support more platforms with Fiddler.)

Comment: oh yes you are right, I just did not look at the whole menu. Post it as an answer, I will accept it. btw, good news that fiddler will be available on mac. Makes your answer perfect.

Comment: Try Requestly - Chrome Extension. It allows you to Redirect, block requests. It also allows to modify request/response headers. I think this is what you want.  http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa.

PS: I created Requestly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand it, Charles' **Map** feature offers what you're looking for.

If you have a Windows PC or VM on your Mac, you can use Fiddler to [capture the Mac's traffic](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#mac). Also worth noting is that I'm at Telerik now and one of our goals is to support more platforms with Fiddler. An alpha version of Fiddler for the Mono framework is now available.

Comment: Is there an official doc to how get started with the Mono version. So far, it doesnt' capture any traffic even if I manually set http proxy to 127.0.0.1:8888 and after checking "Decrypt HTTPS" it hangs forever.

Comment: @coding_idiot: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but it doesn't belong in a comment here. https://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono explains how to use Fiddler on Mono. You may want to send us email (Help > Send Feedback) if you need more help.

Comment: @EricLaw thanks for the work on fiddler for the mono framekwork. is this work in active development? noticed that the latest release is still in alpha version and only updated in 2013 though.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a free chrome extension: [Trumpet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trumpet/cflekmkldaldnelemkkldoaedapbkmog)

Features:

Wildcard pattern

RegEx pattern

Category

File drag

Comment: Thank you! This does what is needed. The difference is that it does redirect the browser to a different URL, but with Fiddler's auto-responder the browser is unaware that the content came from a different source. However, this does the trick for responding with dummy/alternate REST responses from AJAX calls. Simplest solution to getting this functionality on Mac OSX I have come across so far, even though it is limited only to Chrome. At the time of writing, the Fiddler Mono port still has much to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Tamper](http://dutzi.github.io/tamper/), it's based on [mitmproxy](http://www.mitmproxy.org) and it allows you to see all requests made by the current tab, modify them and serve the modified version next time you refresh.

Comment: nice, but this is chrome only, whilst charles/fiddler are intercepting everything, regardless of the browser / soft used.